# yield throws KotlinNullPointerException in buildSequence for maven projects

Tags: kotlin, coroutine

I'm looking into `coroutines` in Kotlin, starting with Fibonacci sequence like this:

```
import kotlin.coroutines.experimental.buildSequence

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val fibo = buildSequence {
        yield(0)

        var a = 0
        var b = 1

        while (true) {
            yield(b)
            b = a + b
            a = b - a
        }
    }

    fibo.take(5).forEach { println(it) }
}
```

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA, when the above code runs in a project created by `New Project` -> `Kotlin` -> `Kotlin(JVM)`, it's working fine.

When the code runs in a project of Maven, created from archetype `org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-archetype-jvm` `kotlin-archetype-jvm:1.1.2-4` it throws `KotlinNullPointerException`.

> Exception in thread "main" kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException  at
>   kotlin.coroutines.experimental.SequenceBuilderIterator.yield(SequenceBuilder.kt:163)
>     at com.github.fdudannychen.HelloKt$main$fibo$1.doResume(Hello.kt:7)
>     at
>   kotlin.coroutines.experimental.jvm.internal.CoroutineImpl.resume(CoroutineImpl.kt:54)
>     at
>   kotlin.coroutines.experimental.SequenceBuilderIterator.hasNext(SequenceBuilder.kt:128)
>     at kotlin.sequences.TakeSequence$iterator$1.hasNext(Sequences.kt:348)
>     at com.github.fdudannychen.HelloKt.main(Hello.kt:22)

Steps in [this article](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/coroutines-basic-jvm.html) don't help to fix the issue. I don't know why it's not working. Am I missing something?

Comment: Could be an issue with the kotlinx.coroutines library. http://kotl.in/issue

Comment: You need to share the 'pom.xml' and your IDE project compiler settings showing coroutines, and IDE libraries.  also check the IDE Kotlin plugin version and the versions of your Kotlin libraries all line up and are compatible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was reported in [KT-18026](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-18026) and was marked fixed for Kotlin version `1.1.2-5`